# How to transfer both SIM and phone contacts to a new phone?

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-5, data-transfer, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace2 and a new Samsung S5 Mini. I have completed the smart switch but it has only transferred contacts from the phone not the sim.

Can you  please suggest me a solution to transfer all the contacts(including SIM contacts) to my new phone?

Comment: Related: [these 12 questions with answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[data-transfer]+[contacts]+answers%3A1) // Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I've just created a "special search" for you, as similar questions have been asked and answered in the past already. Please take a look at the results. If you cannot find a fitting answer there: please return here, [edit] your answer, and point out what you've tried and where you're stuck. Good luck!

Comment: You can use Super backup SMS and Contacts from play store.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the adb pull command

```
adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db
```

from your Samsung Galaxy and restore it to your Samsung S5 mini

Comment: Corey, that only works if the device is rooted. And to transfer that, the other device had to be rooted as well. Talking about different devices here, this method is dangerous: different ROMs sometimes use different table structures, so the restore might break the target device here (I had that once with the `mmssms.db`, so I know what I'm talking about).